# Homotopy equivalence of simplicial sets

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

From Lurie's Kerodon Remark 3.1.6.6 see : https://kerodon.net/tag/00U5. 
It is said that a morphism of simplicial set $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a homotopy equivalence if and only if for every simplicial sets $Z$ composition with $f$ yields a bijection $\pi _0( \operatorname{Fun}(Y_{}, Z_{})) \rightarrow \pi _0( \operatorname{Fun}( X_{}, Z_{}) )$. 
We say that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ to be a homotopy equivalence if there exist a morphism of simplicial set $g : Y \rightarrow X$ such that there exists a homotopy $H : \Delta^1 \times X \rightarrow X$ such that $H_{\{0\}\times X} = g \circ f$ and $H_{\{1\}\times X} = \operatorname{id}_X$ and similarly there exists a homotopy $G$ from $g\circ f$ to $\operatorname{id_Y}$.
The implication of the remark is clear since the homotopy inverse of $f$ exhibits an inverse. 
However I don't know how to prove the reverse implication namely:
If we suppose that for every simplicial sets $Z$ that $\Theta : \pi _0( \operatorname{Fun}(Y_{}, Z_{})) \rightarrow \pi _0( \operatorname{Fun}( X_{}, Z_{}) )$ is a bijection then in particular it is a bijection for $Z=X$. 
Therefore there exists a vertex  $g \in \operatorname{Fun}( Y_{}, X_{}) $ identified as a morphism of simplicial set $g : Y \rightarrow X$ such that $g \circ f $ lie in the same connected component of $  \operatorname{id_X}$. 
In other words there exists $g\circ f=h_0, \ldots, h_k= \operatorname{id_X}$ a collection of morphism from $X$ to $Y$ such that either there exists a homotopy from $h_i$ to $h_{i+1}$ or a homotopy from $h_{i+1}$ to $h_i$. How can I conclude that there exists a homotopy from $g \circ f$ to $\operatorname{id_x}$ ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is strange. It seems to me that the remark in Kerodon is simply false, unless one assumes that at least some of those simplicial sets are Kan complexes or something. What stands out is that with the definitions as stated, "$f$ is homotopic to $g$" is not an equivalence relation, whereas $\pi_0$ should only depend on the equivalence-relation-closure of this relation.

Comment: That's the definition of a weak equivalence. These are equivalent for Kan complexes but not for general simplicial sets.

Comment: Yes, thanks so I think there is only the first implication that is true and the othere is true if we assumed that $X$ and $Y$ are both Kan complexes. Thanks